# How do you access an already running COM object using .NET Interop?

Tags: interop

I have an application that has its own database as a COM component. I need to write an application that links into an already running instance for this COM database using C# so that I can tweek the values in the database and see how they effect the application.

In the past I have written similar applications using Monikers.

Is there anyway of getting access to a COM component that is ready running, from a .NET app?

Answer (score 4):

To use monikers in .NET you might want to check out `Marshal.BindToMoniker` which internally calls the Win32 BindToMoniker function:

```
void BindToMoniker()
{
    string pptxFile;
    PowerPoint.Presentation pptx;

    pptx = (PowerPoint.Presentation)Marshal.BindToMoniker(pptxFile);
    pptx.Application.Visible = Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
}
```

Another option is to get an IDispatch pointer from a window handle using `AccessibleObjectFromWindow` (A full sample is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779363/how-to-use-use-late-binding-to-get-excel-instance)):

```
// AccessibleObjectFromWindow gets the IDispatch pointer of an object
// that supports IAccessible, which allows us to get to the native OM.
[DllImport("Oleacc.dll")]
private static extern int AccessibleObjectFromWindow(
    int hwnd, uint dwObjectID,
    byte[] riid,
    ref PowerPoint.DocumentWindow ptr);
```

The following blog post (related to MS Office automation) by Andrew Whitechapel might also be a helpful resource on how to create and retrieve COM objects in .NET:

> [**Launching Office Apps Programmatically**](http://blogs.msdn.com/andreww/archive/2008/11/30/starting-or-connecting-to-office-apps.aspx)