# How to access Microsoft Word existing instance using late binding

Tags: c#, automation, ms-word, late-binding, activator

i am developing some code in c# where i will be interacting with Microsoft Word. I want to be able to have the option of re-using an existing instance or as an alternative creating a new instance.

Keeping in mind i want to do all of this using LATE BINDING... it is safe to say i have figured out how to get things working when creating a new instance.. i just call Activator.CreateInstance etc..

The problem i am having is how do i reuse an existing instance, for example, Word is already open and i want to use that instance.

Is there an Activator.UseExistingInstance? or something similar??

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, are you saying you are creating a WinForms project, and not setting a references to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, or PIA's, or whatever at design-time ? In which case you are calling something like : Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application"); and using Activator.CreateInstance on that Type ? Assuming you assign the result of Activator.CreateInstance to a 'var or 'object type variable : what is the problem with re-using that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the `AccessibleObjectFromWindow` api function defined in Oleacc.dll. [Andrew Whitechapel](http://blogs.msdn.com/andreww/archive/2008/11/30/starting-or-connecting-to-office-apps.aspx) has some articles on how to use it. Based on his articles I wrote an answer to a very similar question (about Excel, not Word), which you can find here:

> **[How to use use late binding to get Excel instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779363/how-to-use-use-late-binding-to-get-excel-instance)**

There you will find an example how to connect to an already running Excel instance and then automating this instance using late binding.

Update:

Here is a short sample adapted to Word:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace WordLateBindingSample
{
    [ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    public interface IDispatch
    {
    }

    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("Oleacc.dll")]
        static extern int AccessibleObjectFromWindow(int hwnd, uint dwObjectID, byte[] riid, out IDispatch ptr);

        public delegate bool EnumChildCallback(int hwnd, ref int lParam);

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern bool EnumChildWindows(int hWndParent, EnumChildCallback lpEnumFunc, ref int lParam);

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetClassName(int hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

        public static bool EnumChildProc(int hwndChild, ref int lParam)
        {
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(128);
            GetClassName(hwndChild, buf, 128);
            if (buf.ToString() == "_WwG")
            {
                lParam = hwndChild;
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Use the window class name ("OpusApp") to retrieve a handle to Word's main window.
            // Alternatively you can get the window handle via the process id:
            // int hwnd = (int)Process.GetProcessById(wordPid).MainWindowHandle;
            //
            int hwnd = (int)FindWindow("OpusApp", null);

            if (hwnd != 0)
            {
                int hwndChild = 0;

                // Search the accessible child window (it has class name "_WwG") 
                // as described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317978%28VS.85%29.aspx
                //
                EnumChildCallback cb = new EnumChildCallback(EnumChildProc);
                EnumChildWindows(hwnd, cb, ref hwndChild);

                if (hwndChild != 0)
                {
                    // We call AccessibleObjectFromWindow, passing the constant OBJID_NATIVEOM (defined in winuser.h) 
                    // and IID_IDispatch - we want an IDispatch pointer into the native object model.
                    //
                    const uint OBJID_NATIVEOM = 0xFFFFFFF0;
                    Guid IID_IDispatch = new Guid("{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");
                    IDispatch ptr;

                    int hr = AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwndChild, OBJID_NATIVEOM, IID_IDispatch.ToByteArray(), out ptr);

                    if (hr >= 0)
                    {
                        object wordApp = ptr.GetType().InvokeMember("Application", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, ptr, null);

                        object version = wordApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Version", BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, wordApp, null);
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Word version is: {0}", version));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I keep getting `hr = -2147467259`, can you please help @Dirk.

Comment: @AniketBhansali: That HRESULT means ["E_FAIL (Unspecified error)"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In what line do you get that?

Comment: I get that as a result to call of `AccessibleObjectFromWindow` in variable `hr`

Comment: I solved it, it was because of multiple office installations, i.e. of Office 2013 and 2016, resolved by uninstalling one of it. Anyways thanks @Dirk Vollmar

Answer (score 11):

You're looking for Marshal.GetActiveObject.

```
object word;
try
{
    word = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
}
catch (COMException)
{
    Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application");
    word = System.Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. It's the solution I was looking for a long time. Best regards.

Comment: I have process handle, can I somehow get word instance from that handle?