# get the path and name of the docx that is currently running c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, add-in, docx

I'm coding an add-in for word , On the following code I take all the words that is in the file and put them in a dictionary.

```
`
   Dictionary<string, string> motRap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
   Document document = application.Documents.Open("monfichiertxt.docx");

        // Loop through all words in the document.
        int count = document.Words.Count;
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            // Write the word.
            string text = document.Words[i].Text;
            //motRapport.Add(text);
            motRap.Add(text, "blabla");
        }
        // Close word.
        application.Quit();
```

And I want the file name of the docx that is currently running, instead of writing "monfichiertxt.docx".

Can someone help me please 
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access Microsoft Word existing instance using late binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203968/how-to-access-microsoft-word-existing-instance-using-late-binding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/document-name-property-word) property or the [FullName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/document-fullname-property-word) property like this

```
string name = document.Name;
string fullName = document.FullName;
```

Name will give you "MyDocument.docx" and FullName will give you "...\MyFolder\MyDocument.docx"

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

This question has been handled before and having never tried it, 1 google, and 2 lines of code, I get a simple answer. Although as an addin, I'd not have expected you to need to do this to get the word instance you're already part of..

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application") as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application;
    label1.Text = word.ActiveDocument.Name;
```

Comment: You have to know that we don't have all the abilities of finding the answer of our questions/problems as easily as you. Thank You for your answer but that will not work for my case.