# How to connect to existing instance of Excel from PowerShell?

Tags: excel, powershell, automation

All examples that automate Excel through PowerShell start with this line:

```
PS> $Excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
```

This seems to be handling a new instance of Excel, e.g. running `$Excel.Visible = $true` will show an empty, blank Excel window, not switch to the existing workbook.

**If there is already an instance of Excel running, is there a way to connect to it?**

Comment: Do you need to connect to a specific instance of Excel as represented by a specific window? If not you could also look at accessing a running Excel instance like this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316126. The KB article uses C# but the calls (System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"), for example) should be pretty easy to translate.

Comment: Just to complement Ian's answer: $Excel = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Excel.Application') will retrieve the existing instance of Excel.

Comment: Thanks. However, I've just tried that and then execute `$Excel.Visiable = $true` - it still opened a new Excel window.

Comment: @BorekBernard, `[Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')` does appear to work, assuming the existing instance was created by the same user, as user2587683's answer states. Also note that you mistyped `.Visible` as `.Visiable`.

Answer (score 16):

Instead of the usual `New-Object` `-ComObject` excel.application us this

`$excel = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')`

Rest stays the same.

One downside. You will only get the excel "instances" started by the same user that will initiate the ps1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can access the COM object via HWND [Window handle] using [this WIN32 API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317978%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (***AccessibleObjectFromWindow***).

> (See a SO post sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/779363/763026) of using this api via C#)

.

You may have to write an assembly in C# and/or [manipulate P/Invoke calls via Powershell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg981616).

You may give a shot at it & see how it goes.