# How to Quit or Close (not Kill) Word document (process)?

Tags: .net, powershell, ms-word

In our company we are using Windows application to generate Word (2010) documents. Sometimes the document is not properly closed, so another application (yes, they still call it development:) kill word process which is running more than 1 minute.

These killed processes are stored in MS Word's "Document Recovery". These Document recovery is not possible to turn off in Word 2010 (Options/"Save Autorecover info.." does'n solve the problem). When these "Document Recovery" is full of documents (tens or hundreds), the application stops to generate documents and we need to manually clear the front.

I was able to write this script to identify and kill the processes which are running more than 10 seconds, but is there a way how to close it properly (without killing it)?

I found this tutorial to create and quit word document with powershell, but how to connect specific word process with these MS Office method to close document?

[Powershell and Word tutorial](http://www.petri.co.il/generate-microsoft-word-document-powershell.htm)

```
$timer = 10
$date = Get-Date

if (Get-Process winword*) {
    Get-Process winword | foreach { 
        if ((($date - $_.StartTime).Seconds) -gt $timer) {
            $procID = $_.id
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Magenta "Process $procID is running longer than $timer seconds."
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Killing process $procID.."
            Stop-Process $procID
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to attach to the running Word instance as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17681212/1630171), and then close the document:

```
$wd = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Word.Application')
$wd.Documents | ? { $_.Name -eq 'some.docx' } | % {
  $_.Saved = $true
  $_.Close()
}
```

This must be run in the context of the user who started the application, and it will only attach to the instance started first (usually there's only one instance running anyway). You'd need to quit that instance first before you can attach to the instance started second.

Comment: Thank you, Ansgar. I have many winword instances (processes) running on server. Each document have it's own instance. They are running under the same account with which I'm logged in, but the script can't see them. When I run Word manually, your script works ok, but otherwise not. When there are many winword processes, but noone manually opened, then first line of your script generates this error: Exception calling "GetActiveObject" with "1" argument(s): "Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (M
K_E_UNAVAILABLE))"

Comment: How are these processes being started?

Comment: Users download wpf to their workstations and send requests to IIS server. The output of some of the requests is generated Word document. I don't know exactly how it works, but these processes are running with the same account I'm logged on the server.

Comment: Are you (or someone else) investigating why the process that is generating the Word documents isn't terminating Word when finished? Without, you're just slapping a band-aid on a broken limb.

Comment: Hi alroc. I know that fix the cause of the problem is better than this, but I'm admin, not programmer. I would like to get their code and make some research how to get it to work, but sadly, I don't understand it. The application is made by development team that doesn't exists anymore, so I think that this is my only option now..

Comment: Are these other processes perhaps running in a different session?

Comment: Good question. The automatic winword processes are running on different session. Do I have to switch to the same session or is it possible to mainain them from my acual session?

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: All the winword processes are running in session 0, which is reserver for applications in windows server 2008. I just find out, that when I open word document and then close it, the "Document Recovery" cache is cleared (without the click on "Close" in document recovery section), but when I open Word with powershell, it opens new process in session 0, which I cannot access. Is it possible to force it to open document in my current session? Thank you

Comment: How exactly are you starting those processes? By default they'd be started in your session if you start a PowerShell and create them there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the focus in one of those windows and send the keys Alt F4 to Close those processes

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx

there are several ways to get handles to the windows of the processes.

Good luck