# PowerShell Job isn't running any quicker

Tags: powershell

I converted a script of mine to use jobs:

```
Start-Job "C:\Users\user\Scripts\PowerShell\SQL-Server\Database Anon\CreateSpoofDatabase_Resumes.ps1" { $args[0], $args[1], $args[2],  $args[3], $args[4] } -ArgumentList $ServerAddress, $DatabaseName, $ScriptPath, 1, $totalCandidate_create -Name "Resume_List1"
Start-Job "C:\Users\user\Scripts\PowerShell\SQL-Server\Database Anon\CreateSpoofDatabase_Resumes.ps1" { $args[0], $args[1], $args[2],  $args[3], $args[4] } -ArgumentList $ServerAddress, $DatabaseName, $ScriptPath, 2, $totalCandidate_create -Name "Resume_List2"
Start-Job "C:\Users\user\Scripts\PowerShell\SQL-Server\Database Anon\CreateSpoofDatabase_Resumes.ps1" { $args[0], $args[1], $args[2],  $args[3], $args[4] } -ArgumentList $ServerAddress, $DatabaseName, $ScriptPath, 3, $totalCandidate_create -Name "Resume_List3"
Start-Job "C:\Users\user\Scripts\PowerShell\SQL-Server\Database Anon\CreateSpoofDatabase_Resumes.ps1" { $args[0], $args[1], $args[2],  $args[3], $args[4] } -ArgumentList $ServerAddress, $DatabaseName, $ScriptPath, 4, $totalCandidate_create -Name "Resume_List4"
Start-Job "C:\Users\user\Scripts\PowerShell\SQL-Server\Database Anon\CreateSpoofDatabase_Resumes.ps1" { $args[0], $args[1], $args[2],  $args[3], $args[4] } -ArgumentList $ServerAddress, $DatabaseName, $ScriptPath, 5, $totalCandidate_create -Name "Resume_List5"
```

Basically, the script splits a text file into 6 smaller files and then calls the resume creation script using that file list. The resume creation is just using templates and filling in bookmarks using Word COM objects and data from SQL server.

I have run this with just one job, I've also run it with 12 but it doesn't make a difference to the how fast it is creating the resumes. It is always around 2 per second. I can see it is actually running each instance of the script correctly:

```
WINWORD.EXE                  26560 Console                    1    100,556 K
WINWORD.EXE                  24192 Console                    1    102,472 K
WINWORD.EXE                   7232 Console                    1    100,072 K
WINWORD.EXE                   9300 Console                    1    103,132 K
WINWORD.EXE                  21580 Console                    1    101,416 K
WINWORD.EXE                  15896 Console                    1    118,772 K
WINWORD.EXE                  22916 Console                    1    102,352 K
WINWORD.EXE                  34512 Console                    1    101,320 K
WINWORD.EXE                  17984 Console                    1    101,208 K
WINWORD.EXE                  23964 Console                    1    101,272 K
WINWORD.EXE                   4004 Console                    1    101,928 K
WINWORD.EXE                   4700 Console                    1    101,216 K
```

but I am unsure as to why it takes the same amount of time.

Results from checking the jobs:

> CandidateIDs1_part12.txt Progress: 39 /  90
>   CandidateIDs1_part11.txt Progress: 52 /  101
>   CandidateIDs1_part1.txt Progress: 45 /  101

Script being called:

```cs
Param (
    [string]$ServerAddress,
    [string]$DatabaseName,
    [string]$ScriptPath,
    [int]$fileNum,
    [int]$totalCandidate_create
 )

$counter = 1 # counter for timing
$candList = ($ScriptPath + "test\CandidateIDs1_part$fileNum.txt") # path for candidate ID list

$stream = [IO.File]::OpenWrite($candList)
$stream.SetLength($stream.Length - 2)
$stream.Close()
$stream.Dispose()

# Connect Word
$objWord = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$objWord.Visible = $false 
$wordCounter = 0
$recordCount = (Get-Content $candlist).Count 

# loop through candidate list and create resumes
foreach ($candID in Get-Content $candList) {
    if ($candID) {
        $candID = $candID -replace '\s',''

        $templateDir = Get-ChildItem ($ScriptPath + "Templates\Resumes\") | Get-Random -Count 1 
        $templateFile = $templateDir
        $templateDir =  ($ScriptPath + "Templates\Resumes\" + $templateDir)

        $lname = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT LEFT(personFirstName, 1) FROM tblPErson WHERE personID = $candID" -ServerInstance $ServerAddress -Database $DatabaseName

        $sqlResults = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT personFirstName, personSurname, CandidateAddress, CandidateCity, CandidatePostcode, 
            personMobileTelephone, CandidateState, LEFT(personFirstName, 1) FROM tblPErson INNER JOIN tblCandidate ON tblPErson.personID = tblCandidate.CandidateID
            WHERE personID = $candID" -ServerInstance $ServerAddress -Database $DatabaseName

        $firstName = $sqlResults.ItemArray[0]
        $surName   = $sqlResults.ItemArray[1]
        $Address1  = $sqlResults.ItemArray[2]
        $City      = $sqlResults.ItemArray[3]
        $Postcode  = $sqlResults.ItemArray[4]
        $Mobile    = $sqlResults.ItemArray[5]
        $State     = $sqlResults.ItemArray[6]
        $lName     = $sqlResults.ItemArray[7]

        Write-Host "Progress: $counter / "$recordCount  
        $filename = ($firstname + " " + $surname + " - " + $candID + ".doc")
        $filename2 = ($firstname + " " + $surname + " - " + $candID + ".txt")

        $saveAs = ($scriptPath + "Documents\Original Resumes\" + $lName + "\" + $filename)
        $saveAs2 = ($scriptPath + "Documents\Original Resumes\" + $lName + "\" + $filename2)

        ## Word integration
        $doc=$objWord.documents.Add($templateDir)  
        $doc.Bookmarks.Item("surName").Range.Text = $sqlResults.ItemArray[0] 
        $doc.Bookmarks.Item("firstName").Range.Text = $sqlResults.ItemArray[1]
        $doc.Bookmarks.Item("Address1").Range.Text = $sqlResults.ItemArray[2]
        $doc.Bookmarks.Item("City").Range.Text = $sqlResults.ItemArray[3]
        $doc.Bookmarks.Item("Postcode").Range.Text = $sqlResults.ItemArray[4]
        $doc.Bookmarks.Item("Mobile").Range.Text = $sqlResults.ItemArray[5]
        $doc.Bookmarks.Item("State").Range.Text = $sqlResults.ItemArray[6]
        $doc.SaveAs([REF]$saveAs)
        $doc.Close()

        $doc2=$objWord.Documents.Add($saveAs) 
        $doc2.SaveAs([REF]$saveAs2, [REF] 2)

        if ($wordCounter -eq 100) {
            $objWord.Quit()
            $objWord = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
            $objWord.Visible = $false 
            $wordCounter = 0
        }

        $counter += 1 ## Add one to counter
        $wordCounter += 1
        $doc2.Close())
    }
}

$objWord.Quit();
Stop-Job    -Name ("Resume_List"+$fileNum);
Remove-Job  -Name ("Resume_List"+$fileNum);
```

Starting Script:

```cs
# Kill existing word processes
taskkill /f /pid WINWORD.EXE

$candList = ($ScriptPath + "CandidateIDs1.txt")

# Delete all files first
Get-ChildItem -Path ($ScriptPath + "Documents\Original Resumes\") -Include *.* -File -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}

# Generate candidate list
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT TOP 1200 CandidateID FROM tblCandidate" -ServerInstance $ServerAddress -Database $DatabaseName | Out-File -filePath $candList;

# Cleanse candidate list for reading
Get-Content $candList |
    select -Skip 3 |
    Set-Content "$candList-temp"
move "$candList-temp" $candList -Force

[int]$maxsize = (Get-Content $candList).Count / 5.9

$sourcefilename = ($scriptPath + "CandidateIDs1.txt")
$destinationfolderpath = ($scriptPath + "test")

$linecount = 0
$filenumber = 1

$srcfile = gci $sourcefilename
$filebasename = $srcfile.BaseName
$fileext = $srcfile.Extension

Get-Content $sourcefilename | Measure-Object | ForEach-Object { $sourcelinecount = $_.Count }

$content = get-content $sourcefilename | % {
    #Add-Content $destinationfolderpath\$filebasename_$filenumber.txt "$_"
    Add-Content $destinationfolderpath\$filebasename`_part$filenumber$fileext "$_"
    $linecount ++
    if ($linecount -eq $maxsize) {
        $filenumber++
        $linecount = 0
        Write-Host "Writing part: $destinationfolderpath\$filebasename`_part$filenumber$fileext"
    }
}

Start-Job "C:\Users\Scripts\PowerShell\SQL-Server\Database Anon\TRIS-CreateSpoofDatabase_Resumes.ps1" { $args[0], $args[1], $args[2],  $args[3], $args[4] } -ArgumentList $ServerAddress, $DatabaseName, $ScriptPath, 1, $totalCandidate_create -Name "Resume_List1"
Start-Job "C:\Users\Scripts\PowerShell\SQL-Server\Database Anon\TRIS-CreateSpoofDatabase_Resumes.ps1" { $args[0], $args[1], $args[2],  $args[3], $args[4] } -ArgumentList $ServerAddress, $DatabaseName, $ScriptPath, 2, $totalCandidate_create -Name "Resume_List2"
Start-Job "C:\Users\Scripts\PowerShell\SQL-Server\Database Anon\TRIS-CreateSpoofDatabase_Resumes.ps1" { $args[0], $args[1], $args[2],  $args[3], $args[4] } -ArgumentList $ServerAddress, $DatabaseName, $ScriptPath, 3, $totalCandidate_create -Name "Resume_List3"
Start-Job "C:\Users\Scripts\PowerShell\SQL-Server\Database Anon\TRIS-CreateSpoofDatabase_Resumes.ps1" { $args[0], $args[1], $args[2],  $args[3], $args[4] } -ArgumentList $ServerAddress, $DatabaseName, $ScriptPath, 4, $totalCandidate_create -Name "Resume_List4"
Start-Job "C:\Users\Scripts\PowerShell\SQL-Server\Database Anon\TRIS-CreateSpoofDatabase_Resumes.ps1" { $args[0], $args[1], $args[2],  $args[3], $args[4] } -ArgumentList $ServerAddress, $DatabaseName, $ScriptPath, 5, $totalCandidate_create -Name "Resume_List5"
Start-Job "C:\Users\Scripts\PowerShell\SQL-Server\Database Anon\TRIS-CreateSpoofDatabase_Resumes.ps1" { $args[0], $args[1], $args[2],  $args[3], $args[4] } -ArgumentList $ServerAddress, $DatabaseName, $ScriptPath, 6, $totalCandidate_create -Name "Resume_List6"
```

Comment: So each time you are taking the same file, splitting it into 6, then only using 1 of those 6 for each start job call? It sounds like you haven't properly split your script for parallel processing. I would look into how long it takes for the Word ComObject to perform its job for different sized file lists and try only using start-job for that particular series of function calls

Comment: The file is split once into x amount of files, the files just contain a single ID per line which is used to pull the data from SQL server. Then the resume creation just loops through each line in the file.

Comment: How long does it take for you to create a new Comobject? I gave it a go and it takes about 2.5 seconds, that could be taking up the majority of the time.

Comment: Well i leave the comobject open for 100 resumes, as i think it filled up the memory when i left it on at all times

Comment: so each job has an if statement checking a counter, every 100 resumes it closes and reopens the com object

Comment: Maybe add some detailed logging to the script so you can see where the time is being used.

Comment: I don't think we will be able to help you any further unless we are able to see your script

Comment: The logging actually showed more of a delay saving the second file doc2. I just added the two scripts.

Comment: Sorry mate, I can't think of anything that would speed it up. The only think I can think of is moving the get-childitem outside the look, but using the get-random call inside the loop. There is also an extra bracket on $doc2.close()) and you should move the close right after the SAVEAS...You can also try and do $p=[Powershell]::Create(); $p.AddScript({param($objword);$doc2=$objword.document.open(..); $doc2.SaveAs()...}).Addargument($objword) and run it using $p.beginInvoke() before or right after you get $doc. Its just running the $doc2 part along with the $doc part

Comment: You need to identify the bottleneck. Do you have enough CPU? RAM? Does instantiating the COM objects take too long? Do the SQL queries take too long? One thing you could try is using a [job queue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18193195/1630171), start a Word instance per queue slot that the worker script [attaches to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18192408/1630171), and have the workers process individual candidate IDs (remove the candidate loop from the worker).

Comment: I tried running this on my PC at home which is a top of the line gaming pc (threadripper CPU) and it run a hell of a lot quicker, thanks for the help.

Comment: "Top of the line gaming PC" really doesn't say that much. When gauging resource usage of a program you need to look at the details (memory consumption of the process, does it run on just a single core or is the load distributed across multiple cores, ...). `perfmon /res` is a good starting point.