# How to connect Powershell script to an already opened document?

Tags: powershell, ms-word, office-interop, com-interop

I have a Powershell script that performs some modifications with a `MSWord` document. In the beginning of the script PS opens the document:

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$desktop_path = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
$doc = $word.Documents.Open("$desktop_path" + "blabla.docx")
```

But as the requirements changed, I now need to run this PS script within an already opened document. Is there any options to force `PowerShell` find an opened document (by the name for example) and "connect" to it?

FYI: The sequense I want to obtain is: I open the file, launch some macros, call from VBA my PSScript (and here I need PS to be able to "fetch" an opened doc), launch other macros.

Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: why not change the sequence to run macros via powershell? `$doc.run("Macro01")` runs a macro named "Macro01"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The point is that the macros are launching using hot keys, depending on the user choice... And via PS is performed a little piece of functionality, anyway, I will think of it, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should the same as [for Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17681212/5039142):

```
$word = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Word.Application')
```

Note the same-user limitation. I would recommend doing the whole thing programmatically via PowerShell though, [as suggested by Guenther](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52074362/how-to-connect-powershell-script-to-an-already-opened-document#comment91100455_52074362).

If word is not running, is running under a different user, or is running as admin (and PowerShell is not running as admin) you will get an error:

> ```
> Exception calling "GetActiveObject" with "1" argument(s): "Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))"
> At line:1 char:1
> + $word = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Word.Appl ...
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMException
> ```

---

As advised, check that PowerShell and Word are running under the same user. You can so this by going to Task Manager > Details, and checking the user name column for `WINWORD.EXE` and `powershell.exe`

To get a specific document based on name:

```
$doc = $word.Documents | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Document2"}
```

You can check how many documents are open by looking at the count:

```
$word.Documents.Count
```

Comment: When I do: Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word"
$word = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Word.Application')
$doc = $word.ActiveDocument(), I get the message "This command is not available because no document is open." But there is an open document and the question is - how to connect to it.

Comment: Thank you, yes, it works perfectly: $word = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Word.Application')
$doc = $word.Documents | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "HANA_TPO"} Good luck!