# Differences in versions of excel library in c #

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, excellibrary

I added the reference  Microsoft.Excel.16.0.Object.Library to be able to process in Excel.
However, the program I wrote is giving errors to other computers. Because their computers have older versions of this library. Can I make my program workable in all versions of these libraries?

Comment: Since MS Office documents are nothing more than zipped collections of XML files you don't need to use interop. You might consider a library like ClosedXML.

Comment: use `OpenXML or ClosedXML` bypass Interop no need for it these days..

Comment: Was the answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to rely on interop you should use late binding. That way you can reference the installed version of the library at runtime.

> In contrast to early binding, late binding waits until runtime to
>   bind property and method calls to their objects. To do this, the
>   target object must implement a special COM interface: IDispatch. The
>   IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames method allows Visual C# to interrogate an
>   object about what methods and properties it supports and the
>   IDispatch::Invoke method then allows Visual C# to call those methods
>   and properties. Late binding in this fashion has the advantage of
>   removing some of the version dependencies that are inherent with early
>   binding. However, it has the disadvantages of removing compile-time
>   checks on the integrity of automation code, as well as not providing
>   Intellisense features that can provide clues to correct calls to
>   methods and properties. See: [KB 302902: Binding for Office Automation Servers with Visual C# .NET.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302902) for more information about using late binding in C#, and [here](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Using-Late-Bound-COM-Objects/).

However, late binding in C# can be a pain. Anyways, in order to use late binding follow the steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/779710/8291949).