# Access Excel VSTO COM Addin from child process (console app)

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, comaddin

What I'm looking to do is to be able to launch a child process (with elevated privileges) from my VSTO COMAddin that can access the `COMAddin` object for the process that spawned it.

More specifically, I want to be able to kill the addin (via `COMAddin.Connect = false`), do the work that requires the privileges and then restart the addin.

Using a second addin I can accomplish this, as I have access to the `Application.COMAddIns` collection (second addin would shutdown the first when required, start the privileged process and restart the first addin when it completes). I'd rather not have 2 separate addins to accomplish this though if at all possible.

I also know that I can start a new instance of Excel with `new Excel.Application()` and access the `COMAddIns` from there, however I don't want a new instance, I want to be able to control the addin from the running instance.

Any help/ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Excel running instance from an external application by using the [GetActiveObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getactiveobject?view=netframework-4.8) function which uses the Running Object Table (ROT) for getting an active Excel instance and would give you the last Excel instance that was opened - not necessarily the one corresponding with the window handle you have.

```
public Excel.Application StartExcel()
{
    Excel.Application instance = null;
    try
    {
       instance = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
    }
    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
    {
       instance = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
    }

    return instance;
}
```

You may also find the [AccessibleObjectFromWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleacc/nf-oleacc-accessibleobjectfromwindow) function helpful which retrieves the address of the specified interface for the object associated with the specified window.. See [How to use use late binding to get excel instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779363/how-to-use-use-late-binding-to-get-excel-instance) for more information.

---

Note, you can access your add-in methods and properties from other applications. Read more about that in the [Call code in VSTO Add-ins from other Office solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/calling-code-in-vsto-add-ins-from-other-office-solutions?view=vs-2019) article.